# mysql service cannot restart via command

Tags: mysql

When I try to do a service mysql restart. I had this error message

Job for mysql.service failed. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Si I try to do

```
XXXX:~# systemctl status mysql.service -l
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since jeu. 2016-09-01 15:58:09 CEST; 11min ago
  Process: 8611 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 19464 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

sept. 01 15:57:38 XXXXX /etc/init.d/mysql[19491]: 160901 15:57:38 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
sept. 01 15:58:09 XXXXXX mysql[19464]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
sept. 01 15:58:09 Xxxxx systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
sept. 01 15:58:09 bXXXXX systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
sept. 01 15:58:09 XXXXXX systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
```

and

```
root@backup-c1:~# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at ven. 2016-08-26 10:51:32 CEST, end at jeu. 2016-09-01 16:11:01 CEST. --
sept. 01 16:09:02 Xxxxx CRON[20546]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
sept. 01 16:10:01 xxxxx CRON[20590]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
sept. 01 16:10:01 xxxxxx CRON[20591]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 25 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
sept. 01 16:10:01 xxxxxx CRON[20590]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
sept. 01 16:10:13 xxxxxx sshd[20633]: Invalid user tomcat4 from 112.133.231.212
sept. 01 16:10:13 xxxxxx sshd[20633]: input_userauth_request: invalid user tomcat4 [preauth]
sept. 01 16:10:13 xxxxx sshd[20633]: Connection closed by 112.133.231.212 [preauth]
sept. 01 16:11:01 xxxxx CRON[20635]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
sept. 01 16:11:01 xxxxx CRON[20636]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 25 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
sept. 01 16:11:01 xxxxxx CRON[20635]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists.....maybe this is the reason

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop MySQL server then try to restart it